Playcanvas web collision detection
I am making a little game using playcanvas in a web browser. I build it in javascript, and I am trying to add collisions. However, they seem to not be implemented.
I defined two entities : a cube and a ball, where you control the ball. I am trying to detect when the ball touches the cube. I defined them like this :
// Define the cube here
const cube = new pc.Entity("cube");
cube.addComponent("model", {
    type: "box"
});
cube.addComponent("collision", {
    type: "box",
    scale: cube.getLocalScale().divScalar(2)
});
cube.addComponent("rigidbody", {
    type: "static",
    friction: 0.5,
    restitution: 0.2
});

cube.on("collisionstart", (result) => {
    console.log(result) // Just to see what it is
});

// Define the ball here
const ball = new pc.Entity("ball");
ball.addComponent("model", {
    type: "sphere",
    castShadows: true,
    receiveShadows: true
});
ball.setLocalScale(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
ball.setPosition(-5, 0, 0);
ball.addComponent("collision", {
    type: "sphere"
});
ball.addComponent("rigidbody", {
    type: "dynamic"
});
ball.on("collisionstart", (result) => {
    console.log(result) // Just to see what it is
});


I use key inputs in the app.on("update") event to move the ball with the ball.translate method, with these methods :

const forward = (delta) => {
    const forward = ball.forward;
    ball.translate(0, 0, forward.z * delta);
}
const backward = (delta) => {
    const forward = ball.forward;
    ball.translate(0, 0, -forward.z * delta);
}
const left = (delta) => {
    const right = ball.right;
    ball.translate(-right.x * delta, 0, 0);
}
const right = (delta) => {
    const right = ball.right;
    ball.translate(right.x * delta, 0, 0);
}

I searched for event to add to the entities, I tried a bunch of them (collisionstart for example), but they logged nothing.
Did I do something wrong or do I miss something?

You need to show your non-working collision dectection code and code that creates what you think is a  collision condition.
